# Require a File that has been already required in another required File

Tags: php, require, require-once

I have 2 PHP files.

`Connection.php` : Contains a static function which would return a connection `$con`.

`User.php`: Manipulates a User's data (Database) which also requires the `Connection.php` in its script so it can connect to the database.

However this returns an error:

> Warning: require_once(./Connection.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Classes\User.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   './Connection.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Classes\User.php on line 2

**UPDATE**

Here's the directory:

```
/htdocs/Register.php <--I need to require both files here
/htdocs/Classes/User.php
/htdocs/Classes/Connection.php
```

When `User.php` is requiring `Connection.php`:

`require_once './Connection.php';`

When I'm requiring both files in `Register.php`:

```
require_once './Classes/Connection.php'; //No error when required Alone
require_once './Classes/User.php'; //No Error when required Alone
```

Comment: Seems that all your files are not in the same directory. You should specify the correct path to the files to be included (or `require_once`d in your case). Or you could add the directories to the include_path with `ini_get` and `ini_set`

Comment: I double checked the directory, everything works if I only require `connection.php` but when I require `user.php` I get this error, and If I require `user.php` without `connection.php` I don't receive an error.

Comment: Check if you have nothing inside `user.php` that requires or includes connection.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You must have to create folder inside the htdocs*

Make sure your files are in current folder.

```
require_once("Classes/Connection.php");
require_once("Classes/User.php");

// call static function from Connection.php

$con = new Connection();
$con->connection(return values);
```

Comment: you must have to create folder inside the htdocs directory and place your all files in the folder then run the script it will works

Comment: Sadly it did not work.

Comment: check updated answer path must be `Classes/Connection.php` and `Classes/User.php` because both files are inside the classes directory

Comment: It worked! But I had to remove the dot `.` as well in `User.php` when I was requiring `Connection.php`, I don't trust Netbeans anymore...

Comment: yah use `Adobe Dreamweaver`

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once './Classes/Connection.php'; //No error when required Alone
require_once './Classes/User.php'; //No Error when required Alone
```

The above seems just about right, If you are getting error when requiring both files at the same, if is because you are having another file which you are requiring in `User.php` So, check, both files do not require anything at all.

Comment: This is the thing, in `User.php` I am requiring `Connection.php`, I need it, and in `Register.php` I need them both.

Comment: Stop that, just request both in `register.php` what is preventing you from doing that? O